# Installation issues with NPM (Docker) OSX

Tags: macos, npm, saleor

I'm getting two errors/warnings while installing Saleor.
Does anyone know how to fix this issue?
I understand that it's an optional package but it doesn't continue the installation.

```
⚠ Command failed: /app/node_modules/cwebp-bin/vendor/cwebp -version
/app/node_modules/cwebp-bin/vendor/cwebp: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


  ⚠ cwebp pre-build test failed
  ℹ compiling from source
  ✔ cwebp built successfully

**Second ERROR**
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.12 (node_modules/jest/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.12: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.12 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.12: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/@storybook/addon-storyshots/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.12 (node_modules/@jest/transform/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.12: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you get those logs, but your title says you are using Linux 64 bits.
The `fsevents` package is for macOs family and yes it is not required.

Comment: I suppose wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
darwin means OSx.. Actually I'm not quite sure what was the issue but after clear all my environment with command ( docker system prune ) and pull from scratched solved my problem.

Comment: I am trying with Ubuntu 18.04 and got similar result